# DNS record for UPN alias?

Tags: domain-name-system, active-directory, upn

I have a active directory domain `ad.example.com` and I configured an UPN alias `example.com`

When a user tries to logon as `user@example.com` how does it know the domain is actually `ad.example.com`?

Don't I need a SRV record or something in the parent zone to hint to the AD?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From what I've read elsewhere:

As a domain member Windows doesn't try to figure out what realm you're in – it always talks to the KDCs for its *default* realm (the one that it was joined to), and the initial Kerberos AS-REQ sends the whole UPN as an [*enterprise name*](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc6806.html#section-5), allowing the KDC to do that job instead.

So the Kerberos principal in AS-REQ looks like `user\@example.com@AD.EXAMPLE.COM`, and it becomes your KDC's job to figure out where that user actually is (I assume by searching the forest's Global Catalog for a user with matching `userPrincipalName` attribute).

But as a standalone (workgroup) client connecting to an AD-member server, however, Windows wouldn't have a "default realm" yet – in that situation it would indeed make queries for AD-specific `_msdcs` SRV records at the UPN suffix.

Answer (score 0):

The account's UPN is unique within the forest and is replicated to all DC's in the forest. When the authenticating DC locates the account, it locates the domain.